# Extract Time from DateTime? for Where clause

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime

I have a field of type DateTime? and I need to filter just on the time. I'm using asp.net on a sql server.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: yes, it's entity framework

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

> CAST(datetimefield as time)

Depending on your SQL version you may have to use this instead:

> CONVERT(char(5), datetimefield, 108)

Comment: Could you post an example of the query? I still get an error.

Comment: SELECT CAST(datetimefield as time) AS TimeOnly
FROM exampledb..tablename

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DbFunctions from System.Data.Entity ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createtime%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)) to create a DateTime and then make the comparison you need. It's something like this:

```
dbContext.Invoices.Where(r => DbFunctions.CreateTime(r.DueTime.Hour, r.DueTime.Minute,  r.DueTime.Second) == DbFunctions.CreateTime(dateFilter.Hour, dateFilter.Minute, dateFilter.Second));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dateTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var time = db.Tbl
        .Select(i => i.DateCol)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(date => date.ToString("hh:mm") <YourFilter>);
```